# Finding "Next Tuesday" in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

```
require 'active_support/all'
days = 0.day.ago
days += 1 until days.since.wday == 2 
next_tuesday = days.since
```

Above code is not doing right. But below is right. Could you tell me why?

```
require 'active_support/all'
current_day = 0.day.ago
current_day += 1.day until current_day.wday == 2
next_tuesday = current_day
```

Comment: I'm sorry, refining my question. I am using active support.

Comment: Rather than load all of Active Support learn how to load the [core extensions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html). Be discerning and load only what is necessary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, mind that you're using ActiveSupport, so this is not pure Ruby. Assuming that, there is an easier way of doing so bundled in ActiveSupport:

```
Time.now.next_week(:tuesday)
```

Comment: Thanks, i am not aware there exist ActiveSupport API for this

Comment: @fidz.id  - http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Date/Calculations/next_week</a> further reading

Comment: Since when is Active Support not pure Ruby? It's a module and gem, and allows us to cherry pick its features. It's completely pure-Ruby and should be part of the core or standard library I think.

Comment: I presume he meant it's not part of the stdlib.

Comment: Precisely. ActiveSupport is great, don't get me wrong. It's just that sometimes you just don't need/want to use it somewhere and this example will not work at all.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible doing date math using seconds as the interval, but that's old school and I'm sure you don't want to have us old people scare you with stories.

I'm away from my computer so this is untested, but here is the gist of what you want to do:

```
today = Date.today
today -= today.wday # normalize the day to the first day of the week, AKA Sunday
today += 9 # add a week + 2 days.
```

It can be stated on one line like:

```
Date.today - Date.today.wkday + 9
```

Or something in between the two.